# Reverse polarity protection: pros/cons fuse+diode vs. latching MOSFET

Tags: protection, reverse

I want to add reverse polarity protection for a battery charger ic.
What would be the pros/cons with the two circuits attached?

EDIT: the fuse will be a resettable (PTC) fuse.

[image: latching MOSFET circuit]

[image: fuse + diode]

[The circuits have been described here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213961/is-it-possible-to-use-a-mosfet-for-li-ion-reverse-polarity-protection-when-prote)

Comment: What about a simple Schottky diode in series, if you can live with a 0.3V drop? It is fairly significant for a 3.7 V 18650, but probably good for multiple cells in series. For a battery charger, it would be necessary to monitor the actual cell voltage, so there would need to be a protected sampling circuit.

Comment: @PStechPaul I assume the charger is just two terminals, hence wouldn't sense cell voltage correctly.

Comment: I meant that the sense resistor would connect directly to the charger's (+) terminal, and the diode would be connected to the charger output circuitry.

Comment: I use a shunt / bus voltage monitor ic to actively monitor the charging.
Yes, I think 0.3V drop is quite significant for a low powered iot product :)

Answer (score 0):

The second circuit is cheaper. But, from the user's point of view, it is no different from having no protection: in both cases, the product stops working. Therefore, only the fist circuit adds value to the user.